# Multiple queries modifying same row

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating a game in which a player can challenge a random player stored in a database. This is how I am doing this: (MySQL database)

When a user searches for a random user, if there are no users waiting, I set the user's 'waiting' attribute to 1.

If there is already a user waiting for a challenge ('waiting' already set to 1), I match them together and set their 'waiting' attributes to 0. (Basically, I query the database table for any users with their 'waiting' attribute set to 1.)

I suppose my first question would be, is this a good idea to do? My concern is with the synchronization. If two users were to query for a waiting player at the same time, then the waiting user would be challenged twice. Although the time frame between the select query and the update query is very small, this is technically possible, right?

Is there a way to avoid this? Or is it something that I shouldn't worry about?

Comment: You could use a table lock, I think.

Comment: Correct, you should use table lock if you dont handle it in your application layer. Try look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: InnoDB. Though I have very limited experience with databases, and even less experience locking them, if there is a high volume of users and queries then wouldn't locking cause some performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update the "waiting" flag at the same time that  you find two players you want to match, any other queries will see that update. (This should probably be done in a stored procedure to reduce the time between the queries where you're searching for a waiting player, and then updating their status.) If two queries try and alter the same row at *exactly* same time, one of them will fail as the row should be locked for the update.

I'm not sure of MySQL will generate a deadlock exception or not.

Make sure you've got good exception handling in your client app. If you get an exception from this operation indicating that the update failed, try again. You may want to generate a test that will intentionally cause the condition you're worried about and verify that your fix works as expected.

The only way I would expect this to happen is if you're using parameterized queries and have to execute separate queries to find the match and then update the "waiting" flags. Use a stored proc, do it all at once on the server, and enjoy increased stability and tranquility.

Comment: I agree with this. I can avoid the synchronization issue if I update first instead of trying to select and then update. Thanks.

Comment: Theoretically, isn't it still possible for two sessions to see a user IDLE and update him to 1 (at the same time), thereby adding him in two challenges? Unless you lock the row for a user before updating, you always run this risk.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create some sort of mutex situation. Basically, you need to have the query increment some number and then test that it is the right value.

```
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE ready = 1
AND connections = 0
```

then you need to have an increment

```
UPDATE players
SET connections = connections + 1
WHERE id IN (...)
```

then you should check that the connection number is still one (somebody else challenged the same player)

```
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE connections = 1
AND id IN (...)
```

you also need to reset anyone who got challenged twice

```
UPDATE players
SET connections = 0
WHERE connection > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the concurrency part. It is possible for two people  to challenge the same user and get through till the challenge part.

One possible approach is to **lock the row for update** , s that another session running simultaneously will fail to get the lock on the same user id.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Instead, Can you try a third table which has the IDs of the two users like below..?

```
create table users(
   id number,
   name varchar2(200)
);

create table challenge(
   id1 number,
   id2 number,
   constraint pk1 primary key (id1,id2),
   constraint fk1 fk_id1 references users(id1),
   constraint fk2 fk_id2 references users(id),
   );
```

If you want to display users who are not in a challenge.. all you have to do is..

```
select * from users where id not in (
 select id1 from challenge
   union
 select id2 from challenge);
```

The primary key would prevent a user who's already involved in a challlenge to be added to another again.